# How to write a generic test method to ensure that a class has a subset of properties of a separate class?

Tags: c#, generics, properties, lambda

I am endeavoring to write a test method to determine if a class has a superset of properties of a different class. This is for purposes of mapping from domain objects to view model objects and as such there is no relationship between the two classes.

As an example if I had the domain class `Foo` and the view model class `FooMap` I would want to test that `Foo` had the properties that `FooMap` expected it to.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get;set; }
    public string Baz { get;set; }
    public string NoOneCaresProp { get; set; }

    public string GetBarBaz() { return Bar + Baz; }
}

public class FooMap
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string GetBarBaz { get; set; }
    public string NotAFooProp { get; set; }
}
```

Given the properties of `FooMap` for the purposes of this test I want to ensure that class `Foo` has the `Bar` property and the `GetBarBaz` method. Additional methods or properties for either class should be ignored. I've written the following static method to perform such a test but am not happy with my implementation:

```
public static void ExpectedPropertiesExist<TSource, TDestination, R>(params
    Expression<Func<TDestination, R>>[] exclude)
{
    var excludedProperties = exclude.Select(e => (e.Body as
        MemberExpression).Member.Name);
    var mappedProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .Except(excludedProperties);

    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);

    var baseTypeNames = sourceType.GetProperties().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
    baseTypeNames.AddRange(sourceType.GetMethods().Select(b => b.Name));

    Assert.IsTrue(new HashSet<string>(baseTypeNames)
        .IsSupersetOf(mappedProperties));
}
```

The code to call the above is not nearly as succinct as I would like it to be:

```
// what my call to the function looks like now
TestExtensionFun.ExpectedPropertiesExist<Foo, FooMap,
    object>(fm => fm.NotAFooProp);

// I'd prefer it to look like this
TestExtensionFun.ExpectedPropertiesExist<Foo, FooMap>(fm => fm.NotAFooProp);
```

Nor am I sure that the method is as proficient as it could be. What is the best mechanism to write a generic test method to ensure that a class has a subset of properties of a separate class?

Comment: Trying taking a look at the [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation) library on [CodePlex](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation). It gives you some powerful property assertions that you have lots of control over.

Comment: Curious, is the code outside of your control?  Why not just enforce it at compile time with an interface?

Comment: @casperOne I could enforce it with an interface but then my domain object has the potential to become cluttered with interface implementations for each view model that might map from it.

Comment: @nithins wasn't aware of [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation). Looks like a great library. Will probably use it for some future work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really care what the expressions return (you are passing in object as the type for R), you could just remove the generic type parameter R from the ExpectedPropertiesExist method:

```cs
public static void ExpectedPropertiesExist<TSource, TDestination>(params
    Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] exclude)
{
    var excludedProperties = exclude.Select(e => (e.Body as
        MemberExpression).Member.Name);
    var mappedProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .Except(excludedProperties);

    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);

    var baseTypeNames = sourceType.GetProperties().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
    baseTypeNames.AddRange(sourceType.GetMethods().Select(b => b.Name));

    Assert.IsTrue(new HashSet<string>(baseTypeNames)
        .IsSupersetOf(mappedProperties));
}
```

This way, you can call the method with your desired syntax (only two generic type parameters).